# Development of Metro UI (Windows 8) from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

How do I develop for Windows 8 on my Windows 7 machine. I dont want to install a VM. I checked Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview, but I am not sure if it allows me Metro UI development.

Comment: Why don't you want to install a VM?

Comment: If you don't want to install it as a VM, you could dual boot into it...

Comment: Metro requires WinRT and that ONLY for Windows 8 so far. You can mimic a metro look and feel but you cannot go by the rules of Metro while using anything BEFORE windows 8.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, I have very limited space on my laptop harddrive which is forcing me to not to have it as a VM or have a dual boot for it.

Comment: @Anthony Same reason as above!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is set up your Windows 7 machine to dual boot into Windows 8. With a dual boot you can still access files on the Windows 7 machine when you're booted to Win 8. There are plenty of how-to's available; here's one: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-8-with-windows-7/ .

You can also install the dev preview of VS11 on a Windows 7 box to build DLLs the Metro app will use, to experiment with C++ AMP, or just to get a head start on familiarity with the VS UI. Any app you build with that (or VS2010, or VS2008, or whatever) will happily run on the Desktop side of Win8, the same as it did on Win7.

What you can't do is build (never mind test) Win8 Metro apps using a Win7 box only. Yet.

Comment: Thanks I have realised this. I installed the VS11 but found that it doesnt give me an option to create MEtro UI. Thanks for your help! But i cant have dual boot/install vm as i have limited space on my hdd.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do Metro style development from Windows 7.  If you cannot install Windows 8 either directly or via a VM or dual-boot, you will not be able to develop Metro style apps on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Windows 8 Virtual Labs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj206431.aspx) don't need Windows 8 to be installed. Try it out on Windows 7.